# Pointing to libstdc++ from devtoolset - software collection

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, libstdc++, devtoolset

I have an application program `"Cprog"` that requires GCC 4.9 and C++11's `libstdc++.so`.

To fulfill this requirement on CentOS 6, I am using Red Hat's `devtoolset-6`.

This lib is located at:

```
$ scl enable devtoolset-6 bash
/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/libstdc++.so
```

Which I add to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` path variable as:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

At compilation time, the lib is not found:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./Cprog)
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found
...ect
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the libstdc++.so in devtoolset is just a 'link',
try to cat that file then can find that:

```
[root@localhost 10]# cat libstdc++.so
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
INPUT ( /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -lstdc++_nonshared )
```